# Gradual Increase in JVM (heap) Eden Space while running Spark Streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, spark-streaming

I am running a Spark Streaming job which is consuming data from Kafka. Data flow rate is consistent and always within the range, and every spark streaming window is exactly doing the same job. 
But I am seeing a pattern in JVM Heap (Eden) Space, its crossing the peak as time goes.

I understand eden is meant for allocating memory to object when it starts but why its growing as time goes on as number of object must not be highly different.
[image]

From the image above, you can see a trend that memory utilization is keep on growing and there is absolutely nothing different in the code.

Is it possible that Spark Streaming creates more and more object as time goes so heap automatically grows or there is some flaw in code ?
I tried to check memory leak or unnecessary object creation, but couldnt find any.

**G1GC update**
I can see the similar trend while running G1GC. Since I am working on big object I increased the region heap size to 16M -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M.

[image]

I can see there is a jump in Live Set + Fragmentation , it reaches upto 61%.

Further researching on the same I realized eden memory is stable but there is consistent growing G1 Old Gen Memory. I am not sure why, but loads of objects are holding the reference. Not sure why and where in Spark Streaming ?

Comment: Could you please let us know which version of Java are you using? Have you set any GC explicitly (like G1GC)

Comment: Java 1.8, with no explicit GC set

Comment: Then it is "ParallelGC", could you change GC to G1GC and observe if you see the same result, just to conclude the issue with "ParallelGC" you can use "-XX:+UseG1GC"

Comment: My GC is PS MarkandSweep

Comment: CMS GC may lead to fragmentations over period of time - https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/troubleshooting_long_gc_pauses please check with G1GC?

Comment: updated the result of G1GC, its following the similar pattern but with slow pace

Comment: Thanks for updating that, could you file an issue http://bugreport.java.com/ along with steps to reproduce/Test case i will look into that and get back to you. If we found that as an issue in JVM we will fix that..